# 2D arrays and Coordinates

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to just print space in my "canvas" ( with coordinates (2,2) for example) by editing my 80x20 grid  made by █ blocks in the console window.

- Please suggest me better ways of creating the grid in the first place 
  ( I've just learned for-each loops)
- Why do I get those 3 characters after running the program ?
- Why isn't the space on the (2,2) block but obviously on the first row somewhere in the mid ?

[image]

**Code :**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
 uint8_t block {219}; // █
 uint8_t space {32};  // ' '

 uint8_t screen[80][20] {};

 for (auto &row : screen)   // make the "canvas"
    for (auto &col : row)
        col = block;

 for (int row = 1; row <= 80; ++row)
 {
    for (int col = 1; col <= 20; ++col)
    {
        if (col == 2 && row == 2)
            screen[row][col] = space;

    }
 }


std::cout << *screen;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: All c style string must be null terminated.

Comment: If you increase the columns by 1, you can place newline characters in the last column.  This should simplify printing, as you can print the entire array with one statement (remember to reserve an extra slot for the terminating nul character).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some issues:

- C++ uses 0-based indexing. You want `for (int row = 0; row < 80; ++row)`.
- You are looping through the entire array just to add a space, why not use `screen[2][2]=space`?
- You are printing the entire array to the screen, but the array does not include newlines, so you are relying on the console to wrap, is this a safe assumptions?
- Your string does not include the required [null-termination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string), so extra characters are printed.
- You have ordered your array as [column-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order). I suspect you'll want to use row-major instead.

Since you're using C++, I'd probably write your code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Screen {
 public:
  typedef uint8_t schar;
  std::vector<schar> data; //Store data in a flat array: increases speed by improving caching
  int width;
  int height;
  Screen(int width, int height, schar initchar){
    this->width = width;     //'this' refers to the current instantiation of this object
    this->height = height;
    data.resize(width*height,initchar); //Resize vector and set its values
  }
  schar& operator()(int x, int y){
    return data[y*width+x];
  }
  void setAll(schar initchar){
    std::fill(data.begin(),data.end(),initchar);
  }
  void print() const {
    std::cout<<"\033[2J"; //ANSI command: clears the screen, moves cursor to upper left
    for(int y=0;y<height;y++){
      for(int x=0;x<width;x++)
        std::cout<<data[y*width+x];
      std::cout<<"\n";     //Much faster than std::endl
    }
    std::cout<<std::flush; //Needed to guarantee screen displays
  }
};

int main(){
  const int WIDTH  = 80;
  const int HEIGHT = 20;

  uint8_t block {219}; // █
  uint8_t space {32};  // ' '

  Screen screen(WIDTH,HEIGHT,block);
  screen(2,2) = space;
  screen.print();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I learn vectors and classes and those ansi command stuff I will try again I guess .. Thanks anyway ! By the way it doesn't print ,when I run it, correctly ( It prints lines of spaces and blocks, maybe it's that ansi stuff that doesn't work on my machine ? :/ )